# How to produce a merged RSS feed (from DokuWiki and Serendipity)

Tags: php, rss, dokuwiki

I've got an application developed on top of DokuWiki. I'd like to provide a 'News' page providing the latest updates from the internal RSS feed, some other feeds maintained in Serendipity and potentially other locations.

Although its trivial to attach feed parsers to each one individually, I'd like to aggregate this into a single list (possibly a single RSS feed).

Both the DokuWiki and Serendipity servers are not connected to the internet - so I can't use an external service for this - looking for code.

Anybody got any ideas?

TIA

C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DokuWiki already comes with the SimplePie feed aggregation library so you can use that without the need for any additional libraries. Some tips on how to merge two feeds can be found in their documentation:

- http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/sort_multiple_feeds_by_time_and_date
- http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/typical_multifeed_gotchas

Comment: Using the code I've already got seems like a sensible approach - only problem is that SimplePie doesn't find any items in the output from feed.php (although the content displays fine in other readers, and when I tested with a newer DokuWiki it worked fine). Stil I reckon I'm nearly there, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically speaking, you'll have to :

- Fetch the entries from both feeds
- Merge them into an array of entries
- Create a new feed, with your own headers, and containing those entries.

A couple of tools that could probably help :

- [`Zend_Feed_Reader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html), for the first part
- and [`Zend_Feed_Writer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html), for the second part

And you might want to take a look at [`padraic / ZFPlanet`](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet) : it's an aggregator -- there are probably some ideas in there that could help you get started ;-)

Comment: Thanks PM, I prefered Andreas' solution as it uses code I've already got rather than a whole new framework.